# import issue for Google pubsub publisher code in java

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-pubsub

I was reading the google document, i wanted to push my message into pubsub topic.
reference link:
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#pubsub-client-libraries-java

Added the pom dependency as mentioned:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
  <version>1.82.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Example class used:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/pubsub/cloud-client/src/main/java/com/example/pubsub/PublisherExample.java

But after doing everything not sure why the import of all the class is not working through maven.
Error i have in IDE:
[image]

Also, when i checked my Java build path all the google related jars are look like this:
[image]

Add more on it, multiple time updated/clean/build the project, Restart the eclipse 100 times.

Literally I am not getting what to do now, can anybody help what I am missing here.
Appreciated your help in advance.

Comment: What are the actual errors? Are the errors about those classes behind undefined?

Comment: As the import is not working due to dependency not found this code will not run right.. but i wanted to run the code, how could it run it as dependency not resolved.